# Responsive CSS URL Background Images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have two buttons, both which have a background URL property in CSS as the source changes when the user hovers over them. This works perfectly, but the width and height have to be specified, so it creates a problem on responsive devices. When removing the height and weight attributes, the pictures disappear. **How can I make my images responsive in CSS?** Code and source below.

Website: http://parion.github.io/

HTML of one of the images:

```
<a class="sirscribe" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaAlh3Iy7rAcO3MgD_O3Kkg?sub_confirmation=1"></a>
```

CSS of one of the images:

```
a.sirscribe{
    background:url(http://nikcooper.com/img/Box-sirscribe.png) center top no-repeat;
    height:180px;
    width:480px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a.sirscribe:hover{
    background:url(http://nikcooper.com/img/Box-sirscribe-activated.png);
}
```

Image:

[image: Not Hovered]

[image: Hovered]

Comment: You can use `background-size: 100% auto;`, `background-size: auto 100%;` **or** `background-size: cover;`

Comment: See, I've already tried these, but the image requires a height or width in order to display. And if I put those parameters in, the image refuses to resize.

Comment: background-size cover forces the image to fill 100% height/width of the container. You don't need to set a height/width on the image itself, but you do need to set a height/width on the container, there's no way around that.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using an image sprite for your hover effects, it will eliminate that split second where the image disappears while it's loading the hover image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the size on the container (your `a` element). You can use max-width and/or max-height to make it responsive. Then add this to the CSS:

```
a.sirscribe{
    background:url(http://nikcooper.com/img/Box-sirscribe.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    height:180px;
    width:480px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you show me your method of setting the size of the container and using the max-width min-width properties?

Comment: This really depends on your layout. If you don't set the width and height on the `a` element explicitly, the size will be zero - this is why you don't see an image. You may set size in percentages, ems, or rems, and use max-width to prevent it from getting too big on large screens. Or you can use absolute positioning if you want the size to be derived from the outside container.

Comment: Sweet! Actually, I removed the width attribute only, and it began to fill up the entirety of the grid. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sirscribe{
    background:url(http://nikcooper.com/img/Box-sirscribe.png) center top no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    /* otherwise try 
     * background-size: cover;
     * background-size: 100%;
    */
    height:180px;
    width:480px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a.sirscribe:hover{
    background:url(http://nikcooper.com/img/Box-sirscribe-activated.png);
}
```

Comment: None of your methods worked. Neither did they work when I removed the height and width parameters.